# Retrieve response Ajax to js var

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script which insert data into mysqldb in a modal, whith ajax. That works ok but i need to retrive the response to complete an input field and i cannot do it.

Here is the script:

```
$.ajax({  
         url:"insertar_clt.php",  
         method:"POST",  
         data:$('#insert_clt_form').serialize(),  
             success:function(data){  
                $('#nuevo_usuario_modal').modal('hide');  
                document.getElementById('nombre_aut').value=null;
                     }  
                });
```

I need to change value=null for value="response from ajax"

```
document.getElementById('nombre_aut').value=null;
```

Here is the ajax response:

```
{nombre: "Juanita Bilbao"}
nombre: "Juanita Bilbao"
```

I used .done(function( msg ) and works but it has spaces at the begin and the end and doesnt work for me because the textfiel i need to fill is a jquery autocomplete. I just need the data just as the ajax response.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the response in `.success(function(data){});` and use it just like this:
`document.getElementById('nombre_aut').value=data['nombre'];`

Comment: $.ajax({  
                     url:"insertar_clt.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:$('#insert_clt_form').serialize(),  
                        success:function(data){  
                          
                          $('#nuevo_usuario_modal').modal('hide');  
                          document.getElementById('nombre_aut').value=data['nombre'];
                          
                     }  
                });

Comment: look the return data in your console just like this. `console.log(data)` so we can identify if it really returns an array

Comment: this is the console log : {"nombre":"Juanita Perez"}

Comment: then the output is string. You can get the `Juanita Perez` by doing this 
`document.getElementById('nombre_aut').value=JSON.parse(data).nombre;`

Comment: I'm glad I help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that object2 in the snippet below is your ajax response, this should work for you.

```js
var object2 = {nombre: "Juanita Bilbao"};
var objAsString = Object.keys(object2).reduce(function(result, key) {
  return result.concat(key,':',object2[key]);
}, '');
console.log(objAsString);
```